# installing packages on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, sudo

Hi I'm currently on Mac OS X Lion. I had a question that when I install a package like "pip" or "node", which are command line applications or packages. I cannot run them by simply type "pip" or "node'. I have to sudo to run them. Without sudo, it doesn't even find the commands. Is there solutions to this?
I was using Ubuntu before and I didn't have issues like this.

Comment: Are their locations in your regular user's path?

Answer (score 0):

You need to alter your PATH in order to point at the directory holding the new executables.  For command-line apps, the best place to quickly change your PATH is to edit your .bash_profile file in your user home directory.